# My django form returns empty cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple Form, view and a html that renders the form. but the problem is that the form always returns form.is_valid == False.
So I have checked the cleaned data but I noticed that self.cleaned_data returns an empty list.
Here is the relevant code:

```
class GraphForm(forms.Form):
    from_month = forms.DateField(widget=forms.Select(choices=MONTHS))
    from_year = forms.DateField(widget=forms.Select(choices=YEARS))
    to_month = forms.DateField(widget=forms.Select(choices=MONTHS))
    to_year = forms.DateField(widget=forms.Select(choices=YEARS))

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data <<< will always stay be empty
```

```py
def showgraph(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GraphForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            >>> will never happen <<<
            ...
            ...
            ...
    else:
        form = GraphForm()

    return render(request, 'graph.html', {"form": form})
```

```html
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.from_month }}
    {{ form.from_year }}
    <br>
    {{ form.to_month }}
    {{ form.to_year }}
    <br>
    <p align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">send</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Can anyone help with this peculiar problem?

Comment: for your form fields, it it supposed to be a IntegerField rather than DateField?

Comment: Instead of rendering the form fields one by one, try with `{{form.as_p}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<form>` tag should have action besides method so that the submit button can work, like this.

```
<form action="{% url 'name_of_the_view' %}" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Comment: I still get an empty cleaned_data after the modification

Comment: Could you please put `print('Method: %r\n%r', request.method, request.POST)` before the `if request.method == 'POST':`? What is the out put?

Comment: You all pointed me to the right direction which led me to minglyu's suggestion all along

Answer (score 1):

If the code doesn't reach inside form.is_valid(), then it means the form is not valid, add an else to if and print the form.errors() and return the same form to template also add form error in the template to see the errors.

```
def showgraph(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = GraphForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           >>> will never happen <<<
       else:
           print(form.errors())
   else:
       form = GraphForm()
return render(request, 'graph.html', {"form": form})
```

Add error for each field:

```
<span class="text-danger">{{field.errors.as_text|cut:'* '}}</span>
```